# What is the name of this car?

Tags: vehicle-identification, india

[image]

It is a type of "canter". It is used in India to carry people in those jungle safaris.

Can someone give me the precise name/model etc.?

Comment: Well, the manufacturer is Tata. Most likely the vehicle itself is a Safari (go figure), which is a 4x4 SUV. I cannot tell you the model, because it looks to be heavily modified. You can tell it's a [Tata by the badge](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/IUcAAOSwMAxeKCuW/s-l1600.jpg) which is peaking out of the slats in front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a little more digging, it looks like a Tata Safari Storme which has been heavily modified to carry the passengers. Here's a 2015 model. The headlights and the strip (below the hood (bonnet) and above the badge) look to be dead on. The body line of the wheel wells look to match as well. Obviously the roof is removed and the windshield is replaced with the large rectangular one.

[image]